# Error CS0019: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'double' (CS0019)

Tags: c#

I want to use Math.Round function on one object who come `double?`. I try to convert to decimal and after to use math.round function but I receive this error:

> Error CS0019: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'double' (CS0019) (WeatherLocationInfo)

My code is:

```
double? wSpeedInputFirstDay = weatherBindingData.WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].WindForecast.WindForecastValue;
decimal wSpeedOutPutFirstDay = Convert.ToDecimal(wSpeedInputFirstDay);

string wSpeedFirstDay = $"{Math.Round(wSpeedOutPutFirstDay) * 3.6:0}km/h";
```

When I try directly to use Math.Round with the double? object like this:

```
double? wSpeedInputFirstDay = weatherBindingData.WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].WindForecast.WindForecastValue;

string wSpeedFirstDay = $"{Math.Round(wSpeedInputFirstDay) * 3.6:0}km/h";
```

I receive this error:

> Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double?' to 'decimal' (CS1503) (WeatherLocationInfo)

How is the correct way to use the function Math.Round on `double?` object?

Comment: C# only implements builtin promotions to `decimal` for integral types (`int` etc). You'll have to explicitly cast if you want to perform math on `double` and `decimal` in the same statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: `Math.Round` will either output a `double` or a  `decimal`, depending on the input. On the first sample, it returned decimal because `wSpeedOutPutFirstDay` is one. On the second, `wSpeedInputFirstDay` is declared as `double?`, so double it outputs.

That said, the way you declared your `3.6` value defines the type it outputs to.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#real-literals

If you want to declare `3.6` as `decimal`, use it like that: `3.6m` or `3.6M`.  If you want `3.6` to be `float`, use `3.6F`. Declaring it the way you did (`3.6`) types it as `double`.

The reason the compiler throws an exception is that there are no built-in `*` operators that accept two different types. Unless you add them, the best option is to use the same type for both values.

Answer (score 3):

You can try it this way.

```
double? wSpeedInputFirstDay =weatherBindingData.WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].WindForecast.WindForecastValue;
decimal wSpeedOutPutFirstDay = Convert.ToDecimal(wSpeedInputFirstDay);
string wSpeedFirstDay = $"{Math.Round(wSpeedOutPutFirstDay) * 3.6m:0}km/h";
```

Comment: In case OP isn't aware, the change is `3.6` -> `3.6m`, where the `m` notates a `decimal` literal.